# Makefile with different folders reruns script when not needed

Tags: python, makefile

I'm starting a Makefile in a very simple way (as part of a very complicated data science flow):

```
outputs/2009.txt: inputs/2009.txt
    python3.5 script.py 2009
```

The main issue is that even though the files are created, `make` does not understand that the file `outputs/2009.txt` has been created, since when I run `make`, it does rerun the script.

What is going wrong?

Comment: Does your script change the `inputs/2009.txt` file in any way, or open it for writing?

Comment: Show the output from `ls -l outputs/2009.txt inputs/2009.txt; make outputs/2009.txt; ls -l outputs/2009.txt inputs/2009.txt; make -rRd outputs/2009.txt; ls -l outputs/2009.txt inputs/2009.txt`?

Comment: @WanderNauta Nope, it does not.